# How do I search substrings in `Text` very fast?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find the fastest way possible to search for substrings in a `Text` String. Here are the desired output:

```
findSubstringIndices :: Text -> Text -> [Int]
findSubstringIndices "asdfasdf" "as" == [0, 4]  -- 0-indexed
findSubstringIndices "asdasdasdasd" "asdasd" == [0, 3, 6]  -- matches can overlap
```

In my application, the substring is a fixed 6 letter word, but the string to be searched is very long (let's say over 3 billion letters). My current approach is using the `KMP` package:

```
import Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Data.Algorithms.KMP as KMP
findSubstringIndices a b = KMP.match (KMP.build $ T.unpack b) $ T.unpack a
```

But it seems to be a huge waste of the compactness from `Text`. Is there any (preferably concise) way to do it without `unpack`ing?

I know there's a function called `breakOnAll` in `Text`, however it doesn't fit my requirement of allowing overlapping matches.

---

Edit: Per @ReidBarton 's suggestion, I implemented a version that does not need `unpack`, which is indeed faster. However I'm not sure this is the fastest possible.

```
findSubstringIndicesC t a b = let (l, r) = T.breakOn b a in case r of
    "" -> []
    _  -> T.length l : findSubstringIndicesC (t + T.length l + 1) (T.tail r) b

findSubstringIndices = findSubstringIndicesC 0
```

Comment: Do you expect there to be a lot of matches? One easy way would be to use `breakOn`, then throw away one character from the second part of the result and repeat.

Comment: @ReidBarton: That's an idea. I'm a bit worried that the document says "If you need to break a string by a substring repeatedly (e.g. you want to break on every instance of a substring), use breakOnAll instead, as it has lower startup overhead." Does that means it's not advisable to use this function repeatedly?

Comment: Well yes I assume there is some extra startup overhead per search. That's why I asked whether you expect to find lots of matches, or just a few, in which case the extra overhead is unlikely to matter. Anyways there may be some better solutions in third-party packages.

Comment: @ReidBarton: Unfortunately I expect *a lot* of matches. As you could imagine, 6-letters in a 3-billion-letter string could be more than abundant.

Comment: Are you performing more than one search? It seems to me like you should use a specialized data structure for this.

Comment: @Cubic: I will perform about 50 searches, each using a different 6-letter word, but same 3-billion string.

Comment: @trVoldemort Do you know anything at all about the text? For example, is your 6 letter string always surrounded by separators, such as spaces? Then you could just build and index and search using that. Text search is a well understood problem, and it seems wrong to me to roll your own for an example where performance clearly matters.

Comment: KMP or similar without unpacking seems sensible, I think...

Comment: @Cubic: Unfortunately the long string is a continuous DNA sequence, so there's no actual separable "words".

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I bet some good algorithms have already been implemented for `ByteString`. trVoldemort, why would you use `Text` to represent DNA?

Answer (score 1):

The introductory text to [`Data.ByteString.Search`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stringsearch/docs/Data-ByteString-Search.html) indicates that Boyer-Moore is usually fastest, links to a DFA-based algorithm that is better in some special cases, and gives approximate performance ratios. You should not be using `Text` to represent DNA sequences. `Text` is intended for natural-language, possibly multilingual texts. DNA sequences look completely different.

Comment: Thanks. I guess one of the reasons I chose `Text` is because it has this convenient function `toUpper` which is needed to apply on the input sequence, and I didn't find an equivalent in `ByteString`. Is there any simple way I can do the same thing in `ByteString`?

Comment: Uhm ... I could possibly use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` -> `map Char.toUpper`

Comment: @trVoldemort, you could, but you might be better off doing case conversion by pattern matching by hand. You only need to convert, what, four letters? Five if you want the same function to support RNA? Full Unicode case conversion seems like overkill, but you might find it's fast enough.